# POSIXlt list problem with which funciton in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with a list of type Large `POSIXlt` in my project. 
The list is called `time` and has 11315 entries. When I make the command:

```
$ which(time=="1985-01-01")
```

R return the good index 1
but for the entries beyond 91 with the command

```
$ which(time=="1985-04-01")
```

it returns `integer(0)` instead of 91.

Since the data have been downloaded for a project I don't made them but I tried to make my own list of `POSIXlt` and there is the same problem for all the indexes.

If someone can help me it will be very heroic.

PS: here are the information about the version of R and my computer (I'm on ubuntu 18.04)

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          4.4
year           2018
month          03
day            15
svn rev        74408
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
nickname       Someone to Lean On

Comment: 1. Don't use POSIXlt, use POSIXct for your data. 2. Don't compare with a character. Use `which(time == as.POSIXct("1985-01-01", tz = "<time zone of your data>"))`.

Comment: Thank for your answer but it doesn't work. I tried to change the POSIXlt list to an POSIXct list using the command as.POSIXct but the same problem remains, even if I compare to a POSIXcl instead of character.

Comment: I found my problem, the computer was using the format CET/CEST to read the time list and then the problem was for all the days in CEST format. So I change the settings with the command Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT') and it works no more problem.